# PHP, React, MySQL database contact form error

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, axios

I am making a simple landing page using react and php mysql. I want to post inquiries into the php database. I am able to display the response object in the front end console; I am experiencing an error attempting to submit contact form information into a database.  My front end is written using react and currently console logs the state object that I want to post into my MySQL datatbase. My database columns are:

FRONT END CODE:

This is where I am console logging the results; I am experiencing an error in my network saying "Failed to load response data"

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const url = "https://localhost:8080/react-php/insert.php";

class Form extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      message: "",
      formError: false,
      error: null
    };
  }

  handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (
      this.state.name === "" ||
      this.state.email === "" ||
      this.state.message === ""
    ) {
      this.setState({
        formError: true
      });
      return false;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        formError: false
      });
      const obj = {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        message: this.state.message
      };
      console.log(obj);
      axios
        .post(url, obj)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));

      this.setState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        message: ""
      });
    }
  };

  // Functions to  get the input values
  getName = e => {
    let name = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      name: name
    });
    console.log(this.state.name);
  };

  getEmail = e => {
    let email = e.target.value;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
    if (
      email.match(
        /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/
      )
    ) {
      this.setState({
        email: email
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        email: ""
      });
      console.log("Incorrect e-mail, must match expression");
    }

    console.log(this.state.email);
  };

  getMessage = e => {
    let message = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      message: message
    });
    console.log(this.state.message);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form id="contact">
        {/* I am just sending a basic error message */}
        {this.state.formError && (
          <p className="error">Fill all the input fields please.</p>
        )}
        {/* <p>Fill in the next form to send us a message</p> */}
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            placeholder=""
            onChange={this.getName}
            value={this.state.name}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder=""
            onChange={this.getEmail}
            value={this.state.email}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Message</label>
          <textarea
            onChange={this.getMessage}
            maxLength="450"
            value={this.state.message}
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>We will answer as soon as possible</p>
          <input
            type="submit"
            name="submit"
            value="Send"
            onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

BACK END CODE:
I've imported the connection which connects to my localhost on port 8080.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';


header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)){

    $request = json_decode($postdata);


    $name=$request->name;
    $email=$request->email;
    $message=$request->message;

}

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `message`) VALUES (NULL, '{$name}', '{$email}', '{$message}')");
echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con);


if(mysqli_query($con, $query)){
    http_response_code(201);
}else{
    http_response_code(422);

}
```

Comment: Hi. can you share the exact error you're getting when submitting the form

Comment: POST ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is the error. I have checked the connection.php to ensure that the url is correct. Still getting the same error.

Comment: you tried change the url to http instead of https?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
const url = "https://localhost:8080/react-php/insert.php"
```

To

```
const url = "http://localhost:8080/react-php/insert.php"
```

You're likely getting an SSL cert error because you don't have an SSL cert

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: name in /opt/lampp/htdocs/react-php/insert.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: email in /opt/lampp/htdocs/react-php/insert.php on line 21

Notice: Undefined variable: message in /opt/lampp/htdocs/react-php/insert.php on line 21        still getting an undef error in the php

Comment: Right, looks like the SSL error was masking other errors down the line. Your php code isn't picking up the parameters passed through the form from the react code or your react code isn't successfully passing them. I'm not 100% which it is from looking at your code. Are you familiar with the POSTMAN app? you can generate a POST request passing sample parameters to quickly verify if it's the php code or the react code

Comment: params would be for a GET request